# How to make AUCTeX recognize asymptote environment for correct commenting out

Tags: emacs, auctex, asymptote

Is it possible to make AUCTeX recognize the `asy` and `asydef` environments to use the correct symbol for commenting out? In latex-mode the command `comment-region` does add `%` at the beginning of the line. However inside of a asymptote environment this should automatically change to `//`.

Answer (score 3):

The trick is to use [advising](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Advising-Functions.html).  Add the following to your `.emacs`

```lisp
(defadvice comment-region (around comment-region-asymptote activate)
  "Use \"//\" as comment prefix in Asymptote environments."
  (let ((comment-start
     (if (and (equal major-mode 'latex-mode)
          (or (equal (LaTeX-current-environment) "asy")
              (equal (LaTeX-current-environment) "asydef")))
         "//"
       comment-start)))
    ad-do-it))
```